# How to get the TestNG report in VS Code?

Tags: selenium, visual-studio-code, testng

Running selenium test cases with TestNG in VS Code. But the test-output folder is not generated. Tried refreshing the project.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other IDEs, like Eclipse, etc., VS Code doesn't have a plugin for exclusive TestNG activities. In your case, to generate the TestNG report, you need to have the reporting dependency in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```